# How to open a URL and estimate the word count using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_urls() {
var url1="https://finance.yahoo.com/";
var newpage=window.open(url1);
alert(newpage.document.body.innerText.split(' ').length);
                      }           
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: open_urls()"></body>
</html>
```

The code above did not work, how to access DOM for a different URL?
I'd like to open an URL and show the word count of that URL.

Comment: You can load the content of the URL with AJAX and parse that.

Comment: "The code did not work" Is usually not well seen here. You should be getting more precise on what output you get and what you expected :)

Comment: do you want to open a new page and then show the word count on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply open another window and page and expect to have access to it. The web follows many security policies to prevent operations like this, such as the [Same-Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Long-story short, you can't access URLs that don't fall under the *same-origin* as the page you're calling from. You couldn't therefore access Yahoo finance in your example (most likely).

If you were calling from the same origin, you could use an API like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get just the text and do a word count there, or you could even load an iframe and query that: `myIframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML`.

So knowing that you cannot do this from the browser, you *could* do it from a NodeJS application (perhaps also using [**fetch**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)):

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://finance.yahoo.com/')
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.text();
    }).then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
        // perform word-count here
    });
```

I understand that you were hoping to do this from the browser, but unfortunately you will not be able to do so for origins that you do not control.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this out.
In you index.html (suppose) write this:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Index Page</title>
 </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function poponload()
    {
      testwindow = window.open("new_window.html", "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=600");

    }// here new_window.html is file you want to open or you can write any url there
  </script>
<body onload="javascript: poponload()">
    <h1>Hello this can Work</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And suppose your new_window.html is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
     function get_text(el) {
         ret = "";
         var length = el.childNodes.length;
         for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         var node = el.childNodes[i];
         if(node.nodeType != 8) {
           ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? node.nodeValue : get_text(node);
       }
    }
  return ret;
}
 function run_this(){
   var words = get_text(document.getElementById('content'));
   var count = words.split(' ').length;
   alert(count);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='javascript: run_this()' id="content">
  <h1>This is the new window</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So your proposal is what? That Tony gets a job at Yahoo! and edits their finance homepage to insert this JS?

Comment: Well I totally misunderstood and @Quentin yeah thanks your sarcasm made me aware about the real problem here.